# serialVersionUID issue Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, serialization, uid

I just downloaded Eclipse and when I'm getting this warning/error in my source files.

I am receiving a warning from Eclipse: The serializable class does not declare a static final serialVersionUID.

How should I deal with  this issue. It complies just fine in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Every class implementing Interface `java.io.Serializable` should explicitly declare a static final field named `serialVersionUID` of type `long`. It is used during deserialization to check whether client and server are using the same version of your class.

See the [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) of `java.io.Serializable` for further details.

Eclipse JDT offers a compiler check for this kind of potential coding problem. You can configure the compiler warnings and errors in the Eclipse preferences (*Java-Compiler-Errors/Warnings*, section *Potential programming problems*).